# Reordering array dimensions in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

First, some background:
As part of a much larger code I'm reading in data from a netCDF input file. I produce this input file beforehand. The code has been written to expect a term F which is an array shaped like t-by-x-by-y-by-z where time t usually has around 20 values, and x and y dimensions are usually of the order 1000 entries each and z has usually about 5.

In summary, F is a 20x1000x1000x5 array.

This format is incredibly slow to read. It is many times faster to read it if it's written in the format x-by-y-by-z-by-t.

So what instead I am now producing an input netCDF file containing Fnew, which is a 1000x1000x5x20 array.

Now my question: I want to make as few changes to the larger code as possible, so after Fnew is read in, I immediately want to rearrange it to match F.

There must be an easy solution to this?

Comment: The function is called `permute`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cris Luengo commented, the permute function is what you need. This is how you would use it in your context:

```
function test()
%% instead of the current (using 10 instead of 1000 just for demo purposes):
    txyz = rand(20,10,10,5);
    largerCodeOld(txyz);
%% you can now use:
    xyzt = rand(10,10,5,20);
    largerCodeNew( xyzt );
end

function largerCodeOld(txyz)
    % do stuff with txyz
end

function largerCodeNew(xyzt)
    txyz = permute(xyzt,[ 4, 1:3 ]);
    % either do stuff with txyz
    % or call largerCodeOld( txyz )
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I had looked at permute before but had somehow misunderstood how to use it.